# Formatting SQLAlchemy response for Tableau OData Connector

Tags: tableau-api

I have created an API using SQLAlchemy and Flask which returns data as follows:

```
[{"competitor":"Zharnel HUGHES","mark":"9.83","gender":"men","id":345194,"date":"2023-06-24","wind":"1.3","event":"100-metres","score":1266},{"competitor":"Zharnel HUGHES","mark":"9.91","gender":"men","id":209553,"date":"2018-06-09","wind":"0.4","event":"100-metres","score":1238},{"competitor":"Zharnel HUGHES","mark":"9.93","gender":"men","id":209570,"date":"2018-07-21","wind":"0.1","event":"100-metres","score":1231}]
```

I'm trying to configure Tableau Public's OData Connector to accept it without Authentication and getting an error that the data isn't formatted in OData version 4 format.

[Tableau OData Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlzoY.png)

Tried appending ?$format=json and still got same error.

[Tableau OData Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWWdd.png)

I've tried to jsonify the resultset in Flask/SQLAlchemy and I've tried simply returning some text. I've also tried using the SQLAlchemy .execute rather than .query to build the resultset. I've read Tableau's article on the error but it wasn't helpful.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_odata.htm?_gl=1*13fppqi*_ga*MjYxNTE3ODYxLjE2ODkwNzg5NTQ.*_ga_8YLN0SNXVS*MTY5MDU1NDE1Ni4zNC4wLjE2OTA1NTQxNTcuMC4wLjA.

This doesn't seem to be a limitation of Tableau Public but rather the Tableau OData connector. Any ideas how to configure it?